# Windows server 2019 shows 0% cpu usage

Tags: windows, cpu, tasks, resources

I have two servers, one with 2xXeon E5-2450v2 and one with 2xXeon E5-2420, both have windows server 2019 installed. A weird issue I've noticed is both servers show 0% cpu usage in both task manager and resource monitor until I run a stress test. Afterwards, the cpu usage shows normally. Is there a solution to this problem?

Comment: What's the problem? Isn't it a good thing that the CPU is used very little?

Comment: @user202729 0% is not accurate, the CPU is being used but shows 0% until I stress the cpu. After turning off the stress an accurate measurement is shown.

Comment: For HP servers download this https://www.hwinfo.com/download/ and run

Answer (score 8):

The issue must've been caused by HPE's firmware, I changed power settings to OS controlled and the proper CPU usage shows up now

Comment: where did you change this setting?

Comment: I changed it within iLO>power management>power settings.

Comment: Was a reboot required after changing this setting?

Comment: @Eds Yes. It is required.